# How to configure Lambda function (django) outside VPC to access Amazon ElastiCache inside a VPC?

Tags: django, caching, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, amazon-elasticache

How to configure Lambda function (django) outside VPC to access Amazon ElastiCache inside a VPC??
The suggestions from everywhere is its possible only if its in same VPC, but my lambda function is outside VPC and Amazon ElastiCache inside a VPC. How do I configure? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you can add VPC configuration for your Lambda? Traversing the public internet is not ideal both for performance and security

Comment: I am afraid you can't. indeed the function need to be in a VPC (ideally the same) to access AWS managed service like ElasticCache. AWS tutorial is explicit for that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you both for the response, the problem is keeping my function out of VPC is the AWS admin's decision, I was wondering if Elasticache can be configured for the existing setup, anyways will talk to my admin on this. Thanks again for the information

Comment: I thinck that this is not possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/VPCs.EC.html